Why my Azure function app blob trigger is not working when I upload a file?
I have created a blob trigger function app with python.
I also have a blob storage in my storage account.
The settings (local.settings, function.json) seems ok.
After running : func start and uploading a file in the blob nothing is happening.
this is the code:
import logging
from azure.functions import InputStream
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import date,timedelta
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import numpy as np
import os
import azure.storage.blob
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import azure.functions as func
default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    
    try:
        # Process the blob data here
        data = myblob.read()
        logging.info(f"Blob content: {data}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error processing blob: {str(e)}")

I just wanna see the loggings are working after uploading a new file.
I also receive no error after func run.
Can you please guide me how to overcome this?
I can read/write the blob with my notebook but the function app is not working.

Below code worked for me.
Make sure, you have @app.blob_trigger declaration in your function_app.py file.
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="mycontainer",
                               connection="afrinstore1_STORAGE") 
def blob_trigger(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob"
                f"Name: {myblob.name}"
                f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")


You should add the storage account connection string in local settings file as shown below.
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "afrinstore1_STORAGE": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=afrinstore1;AccountKey=Z64j*******JPA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}

I am able to get the upload logs as soon as I upload a file in Blob storage. Enable Azurite by clicking Fn + F1 and select Azurite: Start before executing the function locally.
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5801 Commit hash: N/A +5ac2f09758b98257e728dd1b5576ce5ea9ef68ff (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669

[2024-07-25T04:36:10.600Z] 0.02s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
[2024-07-25T04:36:10.601Z] 0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
[2024-07-25T04:36:10.602Z] 0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
[2024-07-25T04:36:10.603Z] 0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.
[2024-07-25T04:36:10.770Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        blob_trigger: blobTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-07-25T04:36:15.647Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-07-25T04:36:51.968Z] Executing 'Functions.blob_trigger' (Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): mycontainer/Test.json', Id=ce6dfdf2-3bef-4341-a03b-d1b16a78727b)
[2024-07-25T04:36:51.971Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: da9d3ae0-551e-4700-a78a-9a52d312a7b1, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-07-25T04:36:50.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2024-07-25T04:36:47.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2024-07-25T04:36:47.000+00:00    
[2024-07-25T04:36:52.098Z] Python blob trigger function processed blobName: mycontainer/Test.jsonBlob Size: None bytes
[2024-07-25T04:36:52.149Z] Executed 'Functions.blob_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=ce6dfdf2-3bef-4341-a03b-d1b16a78727b, Duration=898ms)


can you please tell me what is your setting in the Azure platform blob? and what where the value of your connection in the app decoration coming from, from where should I grab it?

I have the same settings in my function app and local.settigns.json but still is not working. wonder if it is related to access key in the Azure platform. Because I have no access to it.

Provide the correct connection string and correct container name in path of
@app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="mycontainer",
connection="afrinstore1_STORAGE")

What is this "afrinstore1_STORAGE" exactly? is it your access key under networking in blob azure?

What is this "afrinstore1_STORAGE" exactly? is it your access key under networking in blob azure? when I click on my access key next to my authentication method I receive a permission error. "You do not have enough permission to list data. click to learn more about authentication with Azure Storage. blab blab bla bla ....."

afrinstore1_STORAGE is the connection string name which is used @app.blob_trigger(arg_name="myblob", path="mycontainer", connection="afrinstore1_STORAGE") . You need to fetch the connection string value from here
